# How can I mirror my iPhone to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: display, screen, iphone

How can I mirror my iPhone to Ubuntu 16.04?

I have an iPhone 5 and I just want to mirror its screen on my monitor. Is there currently any way to do that? I would prefer a native solution instead of a VM.

Comment: A suggestion: look into [AirShou](http://iemulators.com/airshou) (at your own risk, although it seems legit and does work).

Answer (score -2):

Airshou is not working properly. You can look into Everycord to mirror your iPhone to Ubuntu. Everycord is available for all operating systems. You can [download Everycord](http://everycord.org) very easily. I hope this is useful.

Comment: could you please expand this answer to include instructions for mirroring to Ubuntu using the app?